# Why I am not getting any Warning or Error when writing ';'?

Tags: java, syntax, format

I have written these three lines below inside my Java code:

```
ArrayList<String> QuestionID = new ArrayList<String>();
;
ArrayList<String> QuestionType = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It compiles and runs perfect without any problems.

Why does it do so?

I cannot understand why I am not getting any warning or error in second line.

Comment: `while (volatile_variable_thats_being_changed_in_another_thread > 0) ;` is a perfectly valid use of an empty statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Somebody decided that an empty statement is valid. That's all there is to it. Allowing empty statements is sometimes useful, for instance for `for` loops with empty bodies.

As an example, here's how to find the root node of a tree (assuming there's a parent linkage, and that the root node has no parent):

```
for (Node parent = anyChildNode; parent.getParent() != null; parent = parent.getParent())
    ; // this for loop has no body, so an empty statement takes its place
```

Comment: THANKS for mentioning the for-loop thing.

Comment: Most IDEs warn about this (or can be configured to), also the java compiler have command line switches that enables warning about empty statements. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html

Answer (score 4):

Because you are writing an `empty statement`, which is perfectly valid.

[Here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/In_java_what_is_empty_statement.Explain_its_usefulness) you will find some more explanation.

From the above link -

> The usefulness of this type of statement is limited. The main use that
>   I can think of is to fulfill the statement required for a loop
>   structure.
>
> Here is an example that I recently used:
>
> while ( sf(++n) != i) ;
>
> This loop will constantly call the method sf with increasing values of
>   n until the return value of sf(n) is equal to i. Each loop in Java
>   must have some code to execute in the loop body. In this case, all
>   necessary work is done in the condition, and so the mandatory loop
>   body is an empty statement.
>
> While there may be other (more clear) ways of writing this bit of
>   code, this is an example of where that empty statement can be used.

Answer (score 4):

Not only is it allowed, but it has [its own section in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6). As expected:

> An empty statement does nothing.

Even more:

> Execution of an empty statement always completes normally.

Which means that the following code:

```
;
```

will never throw an exception. Good to know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#if DEBUG
    #define ASSERT(_x) Assert(x)
#else
    #define ASSERT(_x)
#endif

ASSERT(test);    // Results in null statement in non-debug builds
```

Empty semicolon means there is "empty statement" before that. Thats perfectly valid case.

`;` means "execute nothing";

[Good article](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Speedup-Loop.aspx) about usage of empty statement

Answer (score 1):

";" is considered as a line code without any instructions.

There's no syntax error.

Comment: It's not considered as a line of code. It's considered as an empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

Its a valid statment and similar to instructing compiler to do  nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Empty statement came to Java from C where you could find it very useful for things like

```
strcpy(char *s, char *t) {
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty Semi Colon is a valid token in JAVA and it denotes an empty statement.